# How to show recording time in notification besides app name in android

Tags: android, notifications

I am running a foreground service to record audio from phone's microphone. How do I show the recording time in the notification as shown in the image? It must be updated every second and paused when recording is paused. Please help, I have searched around but couldn't find the answer to this question.

[image: Showing timer in notification]